# Using numeric values to select item from a dropdown box with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onkeydown

I have a multitude of dropdown boxes within my web page. One of these dropdown boxes is used for a single selected value out of a list of options.

```
<SELECT id="Box0" name="">

<OPTION value="1920">my weird description</OPTION>

<OPTION value="1225">other weird description</OPTION>

<OPTION value="3112">some name dynamically fetched</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

How can I add an event to this section, so when it is in focus, I could use numeric keys like 1,2.. to select an option instead of using the mouse or arrow keys for selecting an option? For clarification: if I press <kbd>1</kbd> on my keyboard, the selected value would become the first value from that list, with <kbd>2</kbd> the selected value becomes second value from that list.

I choose not to use a library/framework such as JQuery/Mootools.

Comment: Why don't you rename the options to "0,1,2" instead of "none, first, second"? Then you wouldn't even need an event for that to work, as Firefox and most other popular browsers would choose 1 when you press 1. You can even use "1st, 2nd" and Firefox will select "1st" when you press 1.

Comment: +1 for saying the same thing I said before you did ;)

Comment: The come from a database and don't have a "normalized" value and can be pretty much dynamic (a value can be 15 or 1501), i limit this list though depending on user role/preferences.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify that I want to add the numeric values to the amount of options, instead of values - as the values are dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can solve your problem

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectvalue(e){
        e = e || event;

        var key = e.which || e.keyCode;

        if(!e.shiftKey && key >= 48 && key <= 57){
            var option = this.options[key - 48];
            if(option){
                option.selected = "selected";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <SELECT id="Box0" name="" onkeypress="selectvalue.apply(this, arguments)">
        <OPTION value="1920">my weird description</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="1225">other weird description</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="3112">some name dynamically fetched</OPTION>
    </SELECT>

</body>
</html>
```

The javascript looks little messy because it has to handle IE and all other browsers.

IE does not pass an event object to the handler function instead we have to use the global event object.

Same way the keycode also is stored in `keyCode` instead of `which` in IE.

Answer (score 3):

You could put a 'rel' attribute on each option which would be the required key for selecting that option.  So, for your example it could be:

```
<select id="Box0" name="">  
<option value="0" rel="0">None</option>  
<option value="1" rel="1">First</option>  
<option value="2" rel="2">Second</option>  
<option value="3" rel="x">Millionth</option>
</select>
```

You wouldn't be looking for the onfocus() event though, you would be looking for the onkeydown() (or similar) event on the select box, which could look something like this:

```
var MySelect = document.getElementById('Box0');
var MyOptions = MySelect.getElementsByTagName('option');
var KeyPressed = //detect which key has been pressed. I can't remember the
                 //specific code for this off the top of my head
for (i=0; i<MyOptions.length; ++i) {
    if (MyOptions[i].rel == KeyPressed) {
        MyOptions[i].selected = true;
    } else {
        MyOptions[i].selected = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice one; how ever my HTML is generated from XSLT. Adding rel-tags to it would add complexity in a realm I rather stay away from touching. +1, I love the solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you have less than 10 options, simply add the number to the text:

```
<option value="0">0 none</option>
<option value="1">1 first</option>
<option value="2">2 second</option>
```

or perhaps easier to read:

```
<option value="0">0 none</option>
<option value="1">1st</option>
<option value="2">2nd</option>
```

No other coding necessary

Comment: +1 I added my comment to the question basically saying the same thing right before you answer, haha. I edited it just now as well, to include the "1st" instead of just "1". Great minds do think alike.

Comment: Actually if I look at the time, I said it first ;)

Comment: This looks really elegant and without a single event! I am going to look if I can re-factor my existing framework to use this.

Comment: Seriously? Are you sure there is not some stuff going on with some framework that makes the second focus necessary? Also if you have more than one number that starts with the same digit, a second hit of that number will take you there

Comment: No, it seems I get a fair bunch of refactoring when I would use this. Browser quirks seem to take control - and I hate it when browsers do that!